# How Can I Turn Granular Mycorrhizae into Effective Liquid?

Tags: plant-health

Looking to turn granulated mycorrhizae (combined with other beneficial bacteria) into a liquid to use.  I use a low pressure aeroponics system and would like to use this granular product but unsure how long it would have to soak, also would I need to add something else to jump start the mix or a certain PH level to make it effective?

Any help on the matter is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello.  Welcome.  I need to know more about the product.   Is it Mykes packed in vermiculite?   That will never dissolve in water.  That product is made to add directly to the roots dry.   Mykes WP is a wetable powder you disperse through a watering system or just a plain watering jug.

Answer (score 1):

Only if your product is water soluble

Mix a small amount of the product(half a teaspoon)
with clean water (no chlorine) at (PH 6.2)

The product should already contain food for the mycorrhizae.
If not then simply mix a very small amount of sugar or molasses sugar with the solution.

Ensure everything is fully dissolved otherwise it may block your pipes.